# Not able to fetch data from database GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1

Tags: python, django

I am building a website for grocery store(Pyshop) and have created ten items using sqlite but I am unable to retrieve the names of the products.

In the Pyshop >> urls.py file,  I have added the address of product  path('products/', include('products.urls')),

In the settings.py file i have also added 'products.apps.ProductsConfig' in installed apps.

In the project, we have created 2 models -Product and Offer. In Product we are storing name, price, stock and a url for the image. In offer we have code, description, and discount.

I tried reading about favicon.ico error but I am not able to understand why this error occurs and how to resolve the problem.

Product>>urls.py is as follows :

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index),
path('new', views.new)
```

Products>>views.py is as follows:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Product
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'Products': products})

def new(request):
    return HttpResponse('New Product')
```

Products>>templates>>index.html is as follows:

```html
< h1 > Products < / h1 >

< ul >
    { % for product in products %}
        < li > {{product.name}}({{product.price}}) < / li >
    { % endfor %}
< / ul >
```

I expect the page in which Products name and price will get printed but nothing is getting printed.

when I runserver this error is coming on console.

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
November 01, 2019 - 12:57:58
Django version 2.2.1, using settings 'pyshop.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[01/Nov/2019 12:58:02] "GET /products/ HTTP/1.1" 200 37
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[01/Nov/2019 12:58:02] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2081
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you change your question text formatting, it is hard to read and to help you

Answer (score 0):

When a browser browses to a website, it will try to fetch the favicon of the site under `/favicon.ico`.
If you didn't configure Django to return a favicon, it will return a 404.

You can follow [this tutorial](https://wsvincent.com/django-favicon/) to configure Django properly.

The fact that your page doesn't render is not clear to me but it is clearly not linked.

You wrote:

```
return render(request, 'index.html', {'Products': products})
```

But in your template, you're using `products` without a capital P. Try to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

`favicon.ico` basically the icon of your website on the tab when a user first time go to it. You can register for it online(usually it's done at the end of development).

The reason you don't see your product data because you mistyped the `Product` context with a non-capital P in your template. Either change `Product` in your views to `product` or change the `product` in template to `Product`

Answer (score -1):

you must add products.urls to project/urls.py like this :

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
   ....
   path('products/',include('products.urls'),

 ]
```

Comment: don't need to do include since the url already used the views function `index` which return the list page

Comment: always you create app/urls.py file it needs to include that file in your project/urls.py file , to tell Django about routing in your app.

Comment: yes if there use `external apps url`(calling url from another app) but in the poster question you can see they urls.py and views.py are in the `same app folder` by the import, and there aren't app name decleared with app_name in urls.py. I think you misunderstood include() function [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urls/#django.urls.include)